# How can I make the find tool window split the preview pane horizontally instead of vertically?

Tags: intellij-idea

I like to pin my `Find window` to the right hand side of my IDE.

This makes the preview pane awkward to use because it's so narrow:

[image]

I've been digging around in the options but can't see anything obvious.

Note that when the `Find window` is shown as a popup, it has the horizontal split orientation I want:

[image]

How can I tell IDEA to lay out the find window with a horizontal split instead of vertical - when it is opened as a tool window instead of a popup?

Please note: I am talking about changing the orientation of the result and preview panes withing the find window - I'm not trying to split an editor.

Comment: It's not possible, request is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This apparently cannot be done with IDEA at the moment.
As per this issue raised a few years ago: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157795